# Can't connect to MySQL on bitbucket pipelines (111 "Connection refused")

Tags: mysql, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I try to connect to a database in my bitbucket pipeline and use the service definition as described in the [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/test-with-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-856697462.html#TestwithdatabasesinBitbucketPipelines-MySQL%E2%80%93rootuser), but I get the following error:

```
+ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ptest_user_password -e "SHOW DATABASES"
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")
```

[image]

Here's my `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml`:

```
image: debian:stretch

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '*':
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client
            - mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ptest_user_password -e "SHOW DATABASES"
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      variables:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pipelines'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_user_password'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please note also: `Services in Pipelines have the following limitations: [...] No mechanism to wait for service startup`. Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-services-and-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-874786688.html#UseservicesanddatabasesinBitbucketPipelines-Caveatsandlimitations
I contacted the bitbucket pipelines team and they suggested to add a `sleep 20` to my `script` section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to tell your service to actually use the mysql service. Try that config:

```
image: debian:stretch

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '*':
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client
            - mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ptest_user_password -e "SHOW DATABASES"
          services:
            - mysql
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      variables:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pipelines'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_user_password'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case i was forgot to add mysql service to pipeline configuration.

Comment: I was with a pipeline almost equals the file above but without the mysql-client installation, but it was not working, then I put a `sleep 20`, to wait the mysql initialization and it worked.